# How to display a pop menu in an adapter class in android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I'm very new to android development and I've a populated recycler view with the view using an adapter class. The problem here is **implementing a pop menu when the user clicks the textViews**. I can only access the textView in the adapter class and since it has no activity, I'm having difficulty in implementing a popup menu. I have searched this site and I found similar links but their solutions never worked for me. That's why i signed up maybe you guys could me.I've tried for two nights and I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I always get an error when implementing the pop up menu in this adapter class, it never seems to work and its very frustrating.

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> values;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public View layout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
        }
    }

    public void add(int position, String item) {
        values.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        values.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public MyAdapter(List<String> myDataset, Context context) {
        values = myDataset;
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postlayout2, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final String name = values.get(position);
        try {
            final String postTitle;
            postTitle = name;
            holder.txtHeader.setText(postTitle);

            // I would like to implement a popup menu display here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("KOPe", "3: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the text view a part of `postlayout2`?

Comment: make a method on textview click event in that method show popup, thats it.

Comment: @sam yes please

Comment: @AmitVaghela I can implement an onClick listener on the textView but using the popup menu code fails.

Comment: write an `onclickListener` below the declaration of the textView, and call the pop-up inside it.

Comment: Show us that code and the `Logcat`. it might help solve the issue, right?

Comment: Exactly as `stuti kasliwal` told!

Comment: `this.context = context.getApplicationContext();`  remove getapplicationcontext so line is `this.context=context`

Comment: what doest make a method on textview click event in that method show popup, thats it means ?@SkullCoderz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your **ViewHolder** class in `bind()` method:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(textView.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
                alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<small> successfully done </small>"));
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                               //perform action
                                Log.d(TAG,"done");
                            }
                        });
                final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's fantastic!!, if my code helps you then please accept and approve my answer so that it can help others

Comment: Okay. Thanks once again and also to the others that helped. I really appreciate your help

Comment: nice enjoy your coding